# After upgrade to Sitecore 8.2 and GlassMapper 4.3.4.197 “Cannot create an abstract class.” error appeared

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

After performing an upgrade from 8.1 to Sitecore 8.2 and GlassMapper 4.3.4.197 (from 4.0.3) I faced the following error described below.

[image]

All the `GlassMapper.Sc.Custom` files remain the same and it worked on previous version. I think there's something in configuration changed, or it can be somehow connected to GlassMapper changes in

> IObjectConstructionTask to AbstractObjectConstructionTask

Because this class is abstract.

Update: Here's the Stack Trace of error:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Feature/UIKITTeaser/Views/Teaser/TIC01VideoImage.cshtml' (model: 'DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser.Master.sitecore.templates.DF.Feature.Teaser.Tic01datasource, DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at DigitalFuture.Foundation.Domain.Extensions.Pipelines.MvcRenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
Message: Failed to create type DigitalFuture.Foundation.Sc.Models.Video.VideoBase
Source: Glass.Mapper
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 121
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateMultiInterface.CreateMultiInferaceTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateMultiInterface\CreateMultiInferaceTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.EnforcedTemplateCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\EnforcedTemplateCheck.cs:line 69
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CacheCheck.CacheCheckTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CacheCheck\CacheCheckTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.SitecoreItemTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\SitecoreItemTask.cs:line 24
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.CreateDynamicTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\CreateDynamicTask.cs:line 59
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.DepthCheck.ModelDepthCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\DepthCheck\ModelDepthCheck.cs:line 18
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 97
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:line 160
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.LazyObjectInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\LazyObjectInterceptor.cs:line 58
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.VideoBaseProxy.get_PosterImageUrl()
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideo_Views_Video_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideo\Views\Video.cshtml:line 18
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideoImageCombination_Views_VideoImageCombination_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideoImageCombination\Views\VideoImageCombination.cshtml:line 16
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Feature_UIKITTeaser_Views_Teaser_TIC01VideoImage_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Feature\UIKITTeaser\Views\Teaser\TIC01VideoImage.cshtml:line 48
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Cannot create an abstract class.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 100xception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Feature/UIKITTeaser/Views/Teaser/TIC01VideoImage.cshtml' (model: 'DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser.Master.sitecore.templates.DF.Feature.Teaser.Tic01datasource, DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at DigitalFuture.Foundation.Domain.Extensions.Pipelines.MvcRenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
Message: Failed to create type DigitalFuture.Foundation.Sc.Models.Video.VideoBase
Source: Glass.Mapper
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 121
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateMultiInterface.CreateMultiInferaceTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateMultiInterface\CreateMultiInferaceTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.EnforcedTemplateCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\EnforcedTemplateCheck.cs:line 69
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CacheCheck.CacheCheckTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CacheCheck\CacheCheckTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.SitecoreItemTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\SitecoreItemTask.cs:line 24
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.CreateDynamicTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\CreateDynamicTask.cs:line 59
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.DepthCheck.ModelDepthCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\DepthCheck\ModelDepthCheck.cs:line 18
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 97
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:line 160
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.LazyObjectInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\LazyObjectInterceptor.cs:line 58
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.VideoBaseProxy.get_PosterImageUrl()
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideo_Views_Video_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideo\Views\Video.cshtml:line 18
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideoImageCombination_Views_VideoImageCombination_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideoImageCombination\Views\VideoImageCombination.cshtml:line 16
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Feature_UIKITTeaser_Views_Teaser_TIC01VideoImage_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Feature\UIKITTeaser\Views\Teaser\TIC01VideoImage.cshtml:line 48
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Cannot create an abstract class.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 100xception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Feature/UIKITTeaser/Views/Teaser/TIC01VideoImage.cshtml' (model: 'DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser.Master.sitecore.templates.DF.Feature.Teaser.Tic01datasource, DigitalFuture.Feature.Teaser').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at DigitalFuture.Foundation.Domain.Extensions.Pipelines.MvcRenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
Message: Failed to create type DigitalFuture.Foundation.Sc.Models.Video.VideoBase
Source: Glass.Mapper
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 121
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateMultiInterface.CreateMultiInferaceTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateMultiInterface\CreateMultiInferaceTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.EnforcedTemplateCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\EnforcedTemplateCheck.cs:line 69
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CacheCheck.CacheCheckTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CacheCheck\CacheCheckTask.cs:line 67
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.SitecoreItemTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\SitecoreItemTask.cs:line 24
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.CreateDynamicTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\CreateDynamicTask.cs:line 59
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 74
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:line 53
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.DepthCheck.ModelDepthCheck.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\DepthCheck\ModelDepthCheck.cs:line 18
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 97
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:line 160
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.LazyObjectInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\LazyObjectInterceptor.cs:line 58
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.VideoBaseProxy.get_PosterImageUrl()
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideo_Views_Video_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideo\Views\Video.cshtml:line 18
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Partial_PARTIALVideoImageCombination_Views_VideoImageCombination_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Partial\PARTIALVideoImageCombination\Views\VideoImageCombination.cshtml:line 16
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Feature_UIKITTeaser_Views_Teaser_TIC01VideoImage_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\df0411\Website\Feature\UIKITTeaser\Views\Teaser\TIC01VideoImage.cshtml:line 48
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Cannot create an abstract class.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 100
```

`

Comment: Are you using [type inference](http://www.glass.lu/mapper/sc/tutorials/tutorial17)? That's the only use case I can think of for having an abstract base class. In this case, it would mean that Glass Mapper was unable to figure out the proper type, and reverted to the base type (which can't be instantiated). Maybe all your concrete types are not properly registered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I think the problem isn't there because everything works well on previous version and type inference set correctly. I think it should be something with changes from IObjectConstructionTask to AbstractObjectConstructionTask [link]http://glass.lu/Blog/Release4-3[/link] . I will add a StackTrace, where  ObjectConstructionTask presented.

Comment: What happens if you make the `VideoBase` class concrete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was that we have two solutions in our project and both of them have GlassMapper.Sc.Custom file. Previously it worked somehow, bit now, after upgrade, it seems like the second config file completely rewrites first. 
Big thanks [Mark Cassidy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/73/mark-cassidy)
for great help!